# Conflicting type warning for function calling in c

Tags: c, function

I was going through a c code and suddenly got an unexpected doubt. The following code throws me a warning `:conflicting types for 'display'`, but when I remove void it works fine.
Can someone explain me what is the exact mistake? Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    display();
}
void display()
{
    printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: You need to add the function prototype of `display()` before defining `main()` or just move the definition of `display()` before the definition of `main()`. Also, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`, not `main()`

Answer (score 5):

In pre-C99 C, if the function prototype is not available before a function, the compiler assumes the function returns an `int`.

So `display()` is assumed to return an `int`. But when compiler sees the actual definition of `display()`, there's a conflict because the actual one has `void` return type.

However, this implicit int rule has been removed from C99 onwards. So your program is technically invalid. You can either

- declare the prototype for `display()` at the top of the source file, or
- move the definition of `display()` above `main()`

Answer (score 3):

Place the function definition before main

```
#include<stdio.h>

void display()
{
printf("hello world");
}

main(){
display();
}
```

When the compiler calls a function and does not see yet its declaration it assumes that the function has return type `int`

Take into account that function main shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

It seems that this program example is from some old book.

Now the C Standard does not support the default return type `int` for functions.